# Meteor doesn't start

Tags: node.js, meteor

Today I tried to start meteor but got an error every time:
I don't know what's wrong but before it worked as well

```
/home/denis/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.1s55y3t++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: DDP disconnected
at Object.Future.wait (/home/denis/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.32.1s55y3t++os.linux.x86_32+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_32/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
```

Comment: have you tried `sudo meteor`? Also make sure you have a good internet connection in case meteor is trying to download that meteor-tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual change .meteor/release to METEOR@0.9.3.1 and run `meteor update`